# how to execute another nodejs inside javascript code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

how to execute another js code but using nodejs,, I mean how to do like this, node index2.js inside index.js ,what should I write inside index.js

searching on internet its look like using

const { exec } = require('child_process');

but I have no Idea my brain can't get it,

pls someone give me some example if possible thanks

Comment: `const { fork } = require('child_process'); var forkedProcess = fork("./index2.js");`
Documentation here: [child_process.fork()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)

Comment: Lots of extensive information on the internet. E.g. https://medium.com/the-guild/getting-to-know-nodes-child-process-module-8ed63038f3fa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing that, you're working two scripts with the same language. So, if you have a function or something you can simply import it doing:

```
var index2 = require('./index2')
```

if you need to execute another script written in bash for example... you have to do this:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('python example.py', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
    return;
  }

  // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `child_process` like so:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
var index2 = exec("./index2.js");
```